# Problems with logical conjunction

Tags: logic

There is a problem. I have line like this:
$$
x \in A \backslash(B\backslash C) \leftrightarrow x\in(A\backslash B)\cup(A\cap C)
$$
and I tried to prove it from left, but stopped here:
$$
x\in A \backslash(B\backslash C)) \leftrightarrow x\in A \wedge x\notin (B\backslash C) \leftrightarrow
x\in A \wedge(x\notin B \wedge x\in C) \leftrightarrow ???
$$
and tried from right, bout stopped here:
$$
x\in(A\backslash B)\cup(A\cap C) \leftrightarrow
(x\in A \wedge x \notin B) \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in C) \leftrightarrow
x \in A \wedge (x\notin B \vee x\in C) \leftrightarrow ???
$$
So, to be honest, I'm kinda lost. I tried it two times, but still get different things from both sides. It is supposed to be "truth" and I need to show how to prove it. But I have no idea where is the mistake.

Also other question.
Is it correct to do something like this:
$$
(x\in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge x \notin C\leftrightarrow x \in A \wedge x \notin C \wedge x \in B \wedge x \notin C
$$
and if yes (or not) based on what? Because I tried to find something to base my prove on, but I can't find anything specific, like theorem or definition.
If something isn't clear, please say what, and I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You are getting confused between set operators and logical operators when you write $x \in A \setminus (x \not\in B \land x \in C)$. At that point, try using the fact that $x \not\in B \setminus C$ is equivalent to $x \not\in B \lor x \in C$.

Comment: Could you point me where I can find proof of why $x \notin B\backslash C$ is equivalent to $x \notin B \vee x \in C$? Because if I were to be honest it's first time I've seen this one. And do you have any idea about second part?

Comment: The second part will be fine once you have this fact (the two parts will join up). The equivalence between $x \neq B \setminus C$ and $x \not\in B \lor x \in C$ will follow from the definitions that you already seem to be using.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{|lr|}\hline x\notin(B\smallsetminus C)&\text{Assumption}\\\hline x\notin (B\cap C^{\small\complement})&\text{Definition of Set Minus}\\x\in(B\cap C^{\small\complement})^{\small\complement}&\text{Definition of Set Complement}\\x\in(B^{\small\complement}\cup{C^{\small\complement}}^{\small\complement})&\text{deMorgan's Law for Sets}\\x\in(B^{\small\complement}\cup C)&\text{Double Complementation}\\(x\in B^{\small\complement})\lor(x\in C)&\text{Definition of Set Union}\\(x\notin B)\lor(x\in C)&\text{Definition of Set Complement}\\\hline\end{array}\quad\textsf{... and vice versa}$$